# How to manage Ordering of calling Ajax calls

Tags: jquery

Inside ready function , i am making three Ajax calls which should be executed one after another

I could be able to manage this for 
First and Second Ajax call ??

My question is how can i call thr third Ajax call based when second is completed ??

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // First Ajax call
    var locationAjaxCall = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url + '/OMS/oms1/getlocationscreen?screen_ids=' + screen_ids,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        cache: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: false,
        success: function(response) {

            var resp = JSON.stringify(response);

            alert(resp);

        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

        }
    });

    // Second Ajax call
    locationAjaxCall.done(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url + '/OMS/oms1/fromscratchmodified?screen_ids=' + screen_ids,
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: false,
            success: function(response) {
                }
            });
    });



    // Third Ajax call
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url + '/OMS/oms1/fetchcustomerid?UUID=' + qruuid,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: false,
        success: function(response) {
        }
    });


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.done()` callbacks of ajax call as shown below :-

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
          // First Ajax call
    }).done(function() {
        $.ajax({
          // Second Ajax call
        }).done(function() {
          // Third Ajax call
        });
     });
 });
```

Comment: Thank you very very much . Worked perfectly .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `done` (or `then`, if you want to handle failures as well) function on all of them:

```
$.ajax({/*...first call...*/
}).done(function() {
    $.ajax({/*...second call...*/
    }).done(function() {
        $.ajax({/*...third call...*/});
    });
});
```

...if it really matters that they be done one after the other.

---

I don't think it's what you're asking, but if you just need all three to be completed before you move on to the next thing, you can use `$.when`

```
$.when(
    $.ajax({/*...first call...*/}),
    $.ajax({/*...second call...*/}),
    $.ajax({/*...third call...*/})
).then(function() {
    // Do the next thing
});
```

The calls will be run in parallel, with the callback called after the last one is done.